Import a binary Powershell module with a simple dependency
I've created a solution with two projects using the dotnet CLI as follows:
PS> dotnet new classlib --output Lib
PS> dotnet new psmodule --output PsModule
PS> dotnet new sln
PS> dotnet sln add Lib
PS> dotnet sln add PsModule

In Visual Studio 2022, I did the following:

opened up the solution and added a reference to Lib in PsModule.
changed the target framework in the PsModule CSPROJ from netstandard2.0 to net9.0

Lib contains one class as follows:
namespace Lib;

public static class Class1
{
    public static string GetString()
    {
        return "FROM DEPENDENCY";
    }

}

PsModule contains a definition for a powershell Cmdlet with no parameters, and simply calling the static method from Lib and writing it to the output:
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using Lib;

namespace PsModule
{
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test,"SampleCmdlet")]
    public class TestSampleCmdletCommand : PSCmdlet
    {

        // This method will be called for each input received from the pipeline to this cmdlet; if no input is received, this method is not called
        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            WriteObject(Class1.GetString());
        }

    }
}

The solution built with no errors, so I then went into the bin directory for PsModule and added a module manifest:
PS>New-ModuleManifest PsModule.psd1

In the module manifest, I made the following changes:
@{
// ...

RootModule = 'PsModule.dll'
RequiredAssemblies = @(
    "Lib.dll"
)
CmdletsToExport = @(
    "Test-SampleCmdlet"
)
//..
}

Then I tried to import my module in Powershell, with the bin directory being my current working directory as follows
PS> import-module .\PsModule.psd1
PS> test-sampleCmdlet

Unfortunately, running the cmdlet causes the following error:

Test-SampleCmdlet: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified.

What is going wrong here and how can I fix it?
EDIT
I was able to get it to work by downgrading all the projects to .NET 8. I'm not sure why it doesn't work with .NET 9. If anyone can provide a good explanation for why it doesn't work with .NET 9 that would be great.

I believe this post explains a bit the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78273077/problem-running-ps-module-based-on-net-8-in-powershell-7-2
PowerShell 7.4 is built on .NET 8.0.0.

The following may be of interest: PowerShell Version by .NET Version
